# React Native - this.setstate creating infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native, setstate

I'm new to react native, and I'm working with an API for the first time ever. I've been using the recommended flatlist component to try to manage my call. I'm trying to create a table out of the data (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component).

**So my end goal is as follows: make an array containing the information I need from the call, and then push it into an array in my state. Basically, an array of arrays using data from the API.**

My set up is as follows:

```
export default class StandingsScreen extends Component {

  

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          isLoading: true,
          tableData: []
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagueTable/518',{
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => {
            this.setState({ data: json.api });
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
          .finally(() => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
          });
      }
```

Im rendering everything through a flatlist to make an array of arrays:

```
render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large"/> : (
          <FlatList style={styles.list}

            data={data.standings[1]}
            listHeaderComponent={Header}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({item}) => this.renderitems}

          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderitems=(item)=> {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    console.log(item.teamName);
    const rowData = [];
    rowData.push(item.rank);
    rowData.push(item.teamName);
    rowData.push(item.all.matchsPlayed);
    rowData.push(item.all.win);
    rowData.push(item.all.lose);
    rowData.push(item.all.draw);
    rowData.push(item.points);
    let NewArr = [...this.state.tableData];
    NewArr.push(rowData);
    // this.setState({tableData: this.state.tableData});
  }
```

**However, the this.setstate line is causing an infinite loop, even though the rest of the code works as intended. Basically, it works until I use .setState.**

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying, without using a flatlist? Or a way to fix this infinite loop? I really just need to make an array of arrays using information from the api.

Comment: setState shouldn't be called inside render, because it will trigger render again. this cause infinity loop

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! How would I go about this without a flat list then?

Comment: what's wrong with Flatlist? your problem is about rending, I don't know why you need to resetState tableData when it stays the same